# Can I make Correlation matrix using only character variable?

Tags: r, correlation

My Data set is some development database and I would like to see if there is a way to create a correlation matrix between characters and characters.

```
df <- structure(list(S1 = c("AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", 
"DDD", "EEE", "EEE", "FFF"), S2 = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3"), S3 = c("MK", "MP", "MP", "MK", 
"MP", "MK", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I'd like to see correlation matrix.

Comment: I suppose you could turn them all into numerics (after turning them into factors), though that seems slightly dubious statistically....